# Entity Framework Core: Computed column with persisted values

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm a little surprised I haven't found any information on the following question, so please excuse if I've missed it somewhere in the docs. Using SQL Server (2016 locally and Azure) and EFCore Code First we're trying to create a computed table column with a persisted value. Creating the column works fine, but I don't have a clue how to persist the value. Here's what we do:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(p => p.Checksum)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("(checksum([FirstColumnName], [SecondColumnName]))");
});
```

And here is what we'd actually like to get in T-SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SomeClass]
(
    [FirstColumnName]   [NVARCHAR](10)
  , [SecondColumnName]  [NVARCHAR](10)
  , [Checksum] AS (CHECKSUM([FirstColumnName], [SecondColumnName])) PERSISTED
);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance, Tobi

**UPDATE:** Based on a good idea by @jeroen-mostert I also tried to just pass the `PERSISTED` string as part of the formula:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(p => p.Checksum)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("(checksum([FirstColumnName], [SecondColumnName]) PERSISTED)");
});
```

And also outside of the parentheses:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(p => p.Checksum)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("(checksum([FirstColumnName], [SecondColumnName])) PERSISTED");
});
```

However und somehow surprisingly, the computed column is still generated with `Is Persisted = No`, so the `PERSISTED` string simply seems to be ignored.

Comment: Be aware that `CHECKSUM` is bad for most purposes, up to and including serving as the basis of a hash index, although you can live with it for that purpose since the duplicates are unlikely to have a big perf impact. If you *are* going to use it for a hash index, there's no need for `PERSISTED`, as it will be persisted as part of the index. If it's not for a hash index, consider a better checksum algorithm with `HASHBYTES`.

Comment: Thanks for that information. Right now we're using the column to check for differences of rows with matching ID values in two different tables. From your comment I conclude it's better to use HASHBYTES for eaxmple, so I will look into that. However, the original question stands, since I'd also want to persist the computed column regardless of the checksum algorithm.

Comment: At the risk of saying something stupid, have you checked what happens if you simply tack on the `PERSISTED` to the definition in the method? I doubt EF does any parsing or interpreting, and it doesn't have any need to know if the column is physically persisted (it only needs to know it's computed).

Comment: That did not sound stupid at all, unfortunately though, it does not seem to work.

Comment: "Does not seem to work" in what way? Does it error out? Does EF perform no migration of an existing column? (That would be more or less expected if it treats the definition as a black box.) If done from scratch, does it generate the column as computed but not as persisted? (This would be surprising to me, as it would mean EF does parse the definition and goes out of its way to ignore `PERSISTED`.)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise. I've updated the question; adding the `PERSISTED` string to the formula has actually no effect.

Comment: I was able to use `PERSISTED` with EF Core 2.2 and SQL Server 2016 (although I haven't tried with CHECKSUM, only with a DATEADD calculation).

Answer (score 10):

Starting with [EF Core 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#computed-columns), the `HasComputedColumnSql` method has a new optional parameter `bool? stored` to specify that the column should be persisted:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>()
  .Property(p => p.Checksum)
  .HasComputedColumnSql("checksum([FirstColumnName], [SecondColumnName])", stored: true);
```

Answer (score 5):

After doing some reading and some tests, I ended up trying the PERSISTED inside the SQL query and it worked.

```
entity.Property(e => e.Duration_ms)
      .HasComputedColumnSql("DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, 0, duration) PERSISTED");
```

The generated migration was the following:

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<long>(
            name: "duration_ms",
            table: "MyTable",
            nullable: true,
            computedColumnSql: "DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, 0, duration) PERSISTED");
```

To check on the database whether it is actually persisted I ran the following:

```
select is_persisted, name from sys.computed_columns where is_persisted = 1
```

and the column that I've created is there.

Comment: Thanks. Which version of EF Core are you using?

Comment: @OnkelToob 2.0.1

Comment: Then it should have worked in my code, too (see the update section of my post). Only difference I can spot: you're not using any parenthesis. Unfortunately, we have moved on in the meantime so I can't get back to this topic anymore.

Answer (score 3):

" You may also specify that a computed column be stored (sometimes called persisted), meaning that it is computed on every update of the row, and is stored on disk alongside regular columns:"

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeClass>(entity =>
{
     entity.Property(p => p.Checksum)
    .HasComputedColumnSql("(checksum([FirstColumnName], [SecondColumnName]), stored: true);
});
```

This is taken (and slightly modified) from Microsoft Docs.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#computed-columns